# Why do I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.client' " in Pycharm even after installing tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow using pip through Terminal on my Mac and I am trying to use it in Pycharm. But for some reason, I keep getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.client'
```

I am running this code:

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)
```

I have looked at this page for basic installation (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and after following the instructions in Terminal I can run this code:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

And this is the corresponding output:

```
2020-07-15 10:57:44.397351: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-07-15 10:57:44.436720: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x12aa14200 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-15 10:57:44.436757: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version 
tf.Tensor(-627.3514, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Hopefully, I have provided enough details to sort the issue, I am trying to run basic ML using tensorflow :)

Comment: Pycharm uses a virtual environment for each of the projects. If you go under settings -> python interpreter, you can check which one you're running. I expect it's installed under a different environment and you'll be able to switch it to the correct one.

Comment: I am surprised it was such a simple problem! Pycharm was using a virtual interpreter. Thanks a lot, I was searching for other unrelated issues :)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so you can close it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm uses a virtual environment for each of the projects. If you go under settings -> python interpreter (see image), you can check which one you're running. I expect it's installed under a different environment and you'll be able to switch it to the correct one.

[image: Under settings, select interpreter]